# Teradata drop statistics if statistics exist

Tags: teradata

DDL/DML script is modifying table structure, and presence of stats on columns stops it from proceeding.
Solution found was - drop the stats of columns that are being modified/dropped first.

However, if the stats do not exist, script is then, in turn, aborted when trying to drop these stats.

What is a cheap way to implement "if stats exist drop stats" logic?

Comment: How is this script run, BTEQ?

Comment: SQL, so it can be BTEQ as well

Comment: In the BTEQ script there's probably a MAXERROR which causes the script to fail, in that case you simply `.SET ERRORLEVEL 3582 severity 0;` before the DROP, which results in no failure for missing stats. Or you check first if the stats exists in `dbc.StatsV` and then skip the collect if no row returned.

Comment: @dieter, could you move your comment to the answers section, so I could accept it as a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This one seems to be working as intended in SQL*Assistant, per Dieter's feedback:

```
select * from dbc.StatsV
where tablename='${table_name}'
  and columnName='${column_name}'
;

.IF ACTIVITYCOUNT>0 THEN .GOTO lbl_drop;

select 'Stats not found for column ${column_name}';
.EXIT; 

.LABEL lbl_drop;
select 'Dropping stats for column ${column_name}';
DROP STATISTICS ON ${table_name} COLUMN ${column_name};
```